# Does it required another having some additional columns in where clause

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have an index idx_tablename_col1col2col3 on Table1 (Col1, Col2, col3)

My query looks below

```
select * from table1
where col1 = @col1 and col2 = @col2

select * from table1
where col2 = @col2 and col3 = @col3

select * from table1
where col1 = @col1 and col3 = @col3
```

Does it required to create 3 indexes for each statement or is it enough with existing index which is mentioned above..

```
select * from table1
where col1 = @col1 and col2 = @col2

select * from table1
where col2 = @col2 and col3 = @col3

select * from table1
where col1 = @col1 and col3 = @col3
```

Comment: for the 2nd query, you need to create another index with (Col2, Col3), but it really depends on how your table looks like and the trade off for creating another index. need to test

Comment: and the 3rd query will partially benefit from the col1 part of the index, but won't be able to use col3,

Comment: So we should have 3 indexes for above three statements right ??

Comment: Required by what exactly? What is your goal?

Comment: No index is *required*, technically, and depending on your column values, an index is not always useful. If `col2` only contains 4 unique values evenly distributed across a 10 million row table, for example, an index on it will almost never get used as it will be deemed not selective enough. The `SELECT *` means the server must read all columns from the clustered index in any case, so the extra I/O from index seeks is weighed against that. Although creating too many indexes is generally not as harmful as creating too few, it's still something to watch out for.

Comment: Imagine I am using the above three statement in one stored proc. And instead select *  I can use select list of column those I can add in index  as included columns.

Also all columns which are in where condition having different data

In this case can you please suggest